# C#: design pattern for background work / communication without abusing Task.Run

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, threadpool

I have a c# .net (4.7.2) rest api web app which needs to communicate (http) periodically with a group of up to 100 devices.
Currently we basically have a event handler that intially makes a single `Task.Run` (containing communication work*) per device. At the end of each such a `Task.Run` an event will be triggered so that this event handler fires again. So when having 100 devices we have approximatley 100  short-lived "background worker threads" running, which all die and cause a `Task.Run` again in a time period of ~ 3 seconds.
As it turns out this seems to be very expensive - in fact I am suspecting this architecture to cause severe problems like 'freezes' from time to time.
I understand that this is not best practise and that calling `Task.Run` is not free, but spinning up
up to 100 threads periodically should not be that big of an issue - at least that's what I thougt.
I don't care if the the Tasks beeing enqueued on the thread pool are worked off with a little delay because of Task management.

So I am wondering which architecture would be appropriate for a dynamic growing/shrinking background work load that consists mainly of "asyncable" code.

Despite of following best practises - is there really a big pit fall here with this `Task.Run` / `Eventhandler` approach?

*The main work consists of establishing a http connection and waiting for its result. Finally database read/writes have to be done. So it could be done by using async code.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: I already googled that one but it seems to be designed for windos form applications

Comment: it would help then to edit your post to include what you are working with then; you mention `web app` OK, using what?

Comment: agreed - updated.

Comment: I would look at using await etc to start all 100 requests without needing a thread per request.

Comment: From what I understand you start 100 tasks at once, which puts suddenly the system under heavy pressure. Is there a reason that you don't `await` each task to complete before starting the next one?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use **Hangfire** to do this continuously. You can access your device via APIs and hand fire connect with all of its and you main devices.

It can show you reports and state of activities and threads and you can program it. I found out it is more reliable and stable that running a thread!

On the other hand, you can use "Observer Design Pattern" in your sub-applications. When the time or Event fire all subscribers in your code can fire and do answer to you.

you can read more in here :

[Observer Design Pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/observer)

Answer (score 1):

For the problem that you describe perfectly suits [Durable Task Freamork](https://github.com/Azure/durabletask/wiki). 
From the box, you will have:

1. possibility to scale (due to the architecture of DTF use ServiceBus and each instance can process work)
2. you can control the execution
3. provides the possibility to configure the level of parallelism

Also for long-running processing, you can use Azure Durable Function.